# Why does FileStream feed FtpWebRequest but not MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I'm using the msdn example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

I changed the FileStream to a MemoryStream and it doesn't read the bytes

when I change it back to FileStream it works fine.

Any clue?

Thanks

```
        CompressMemoryStream();
        Stream requestStream = _request.EndGetRequestStream(ar);
        const int bufferLength = 2048;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
        int count = 0;
        int readBytes = 0;

        do
        {
            //MemoryStream _compressedOutStream 
            //is created/filled by 'CompressMemoryStream()'
            readBytes = _compressedOutStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
            count += readBytes;
        }
        while (readBytes != 0);
        requestStream.Close();
        state.Request.BeginGetResponse(
            new AsyncCallback(EndGetResponseCallback),
            state
        );
```

Comment: Is there a difference in the `Position` when you read into a memory stream vs. the file stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the value of `readBytes` on the first iteration through the loop?

My first guess would be that you made the same mistake that I often make: writing to a stream, then forgetting to rewind it to the beginning before starting to read back from it. If that's the case, then `readBytes` will be zero on the first (and only) loop iteration, because you're at the end of the stream -- there's nothing to read.

Try setting `stream.Position = 0` before you start reading.